# Script to print last login in Unix

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to print the last login information of user in a .csv format.

I tried `last` and `lastlog` commands but getting errors.

Error for `last`:

```
/usr/bin/last patrol
/var/adm/wtmpx: No such file or directory
```

Error for `lastlog`:

```
/var/adm/lastlog -u asaifi001
bash: /var/adm/lastlog: Permission denied
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to share `uname -a` output because these command do not give me any errors on Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to run this commands as root in some systems.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `/var/adm` I think you are using Solaris.

Somehow `/var/adm/wtmpx` is removed. Try to recreate the file (as root) using:

```
touch /var/adm/wtmpx
chown adm:adm /var/adm/wtmpx
```

`/var/adm/lastlog` is not a command, it is a logfile which can be read by `finger`. See also `man finger` for details.